# How do I iterate over a column dataframe made of lists with an index made of other column dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, iteration

So I have a dataframe with different columns. I want to use three. One is a list of different sizes, other two are two columns made of just one number. I want to create a new column made of the combination of the three. One of the columns will select the index in the column made of lists, and then that value of the list will multiply the value of the other column at that row.

Sample of the data:
df['actual'] = 1, 4, 3, 6, 4 ,7 ,2...
df['relative track'] = 2, 0 ,1, 5, 3, 4...
df['weights'] = [250,320, 250, 320], [250, 250, 500, 500, 250], [250, 300, 300]...

So far I have somehting like this but it's wrong as I don't know how to continue.

```
    #Create relative weight variable

df['relative_weigth'] = df['weights'].map(lambda x: i*df['actual'] for i in x)
```

So instead of using i I want to use the relative_track as an index

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the data showing only the columns that are relevant.

Comment: yeah, i will edit the question

Comment: Sample of the data: df['actual'] = 1, 4, 3, 6, 4 ,7 ,2... df['relative track'] = 2, 0 ,1, 5, 3, 4... df['weights'] = [250,320, 250, 320], [250, 250, 500, 500, 250], [250, 300, 300]...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you select from the List in `weights` using the index from `relative track` and the multiply this by `actual` and place the result in a new column `rel weight`. If this is correct then you could use:

```
def func(r):
    print(r)
    idx = r['relative track']
    if idx >= len(r['weights']):
                  return None
    weight = r['weights'][idx]
    return r['actual'] * weight
             
df['rel weight'] = df.apply(func, axis = 1)
```

this produces, from the data shown:

```
   actual  relative track                    weights  rel weight
0       1               2       [250, 320, 250, 320]         250
1       4               0  [250, 250, 500, 500, 250]        1000
2       3               1            [250, 300, 300]         900
```

Comment: it appears to me this IndexError: tuple index out of range, could be because you are not using the index of the relative track, but the whole series instead? Or maybe because it's a tuple, the variable weightS?

Comment: Surely it is because in the row giving the error there is no value in `weights` at the index position given by the relative track (ie weights List is too short). You can see the code does work in my example. It just goes row-by_row which is what `r` is in the function.I suggest you need to examine the data and find which row is causing the problem. I've added a line to my code which will help you find the row causing the problem (it puts NaN in the new column).